# Deferred Resolve

Tags: javascript, deferred, qobject, qtwebengine

I am trying to wrap a JS Async call with deferred so that I can get the response back. This function is a `QtWebEngine` function and hence it is asynchronous. However I want to be able to wait for the response.

```
deferred = $.Deferred();

result = deferred.resolve(host.callMethod());

$.when(result.promise()).done(function(value)
{
    alert(value)
});
```

I was expecting that the value to the call back will be the output of the `Host.callMethod`.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: How is `host.callMethod()` dealing with async? Is it returning a promise or taking a callback as an argument?

Comment: Try `host.callMethod(function(deferred.resolve){ return deferred.promise(); })` OR  `host.callMethod(function(data){ deferred.resolve(data);   return deferred.promise(); })`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. The hostMethod returns a promise. It worked with deferred.promise :)